# Interpolation in rails when making an API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailgun

I have the following code in a controller action:

```
RestClient.post("https://api:#{ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']}" \
                  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/#{ENV['MAILGUN_ALIAS']}/members",
                    :subscribed => true,
                    :address => email_address)
```

I am using .env gem to handle the environment variables. I am getting a 401 unauthorized error, however if I paste in the api key and alias, the request goes through. I can do a puts on ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'] and see the value in the console so I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Have you check if the environments variables are correctly set? Save the URL into a variable and place a `byebug` at the next line. Then check the contents of the variable when the breakpoint hits. (`c = continue`, `n = next`, `s = step into`)

Answer (score 0):

Gah! Tell me what is different about this:

```
def email_signup
    email_address = params[:email_address]

    response = RestClient.post("https://api:#{ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']}" \
                  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/#{ENV['MAILGUN_ALIAS']}/members",
                  :subscribed => true,
                  :address => email_address)
    redirect_to jobs_url, success: "Thanks for Signing Up!"

    rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
      redirect_to jobs_url, error: e
 end
```

Came back with a fresh set of eyes and this worked.

Comment: Did you set `email_address = params[:email_address]` in the question?

Comment: Yes...that was there previously.

Comment: The difference might be that you restarted the server when coming back and that the`.env` file was reloaded.